# How do I get the Panel ElementRef of Mat Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

According to the [MatAutocomplete documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete), there is a `panel` property on MatAutocomplete class that will give you the panel's elementRef.

> panel: ElementRef
>
> Element for the panel containing the autocomplete options.

I am struggling to get this to work though as the autocomplete.panel is always undefined? What am I missing?

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
```

```
  @ViewChild("auto") autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.autocomplete.panel); // undefined??
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-panel-answer-k2p8j6?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that the element will only be available when the panel is open and the element is in the DOM. Which makes sense if you think about it...

See my [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-panel-answer?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts) to see what I mean. Take note that the element is not yet added to the view on the `(opened)` event. Which means you will have to add a setTimeout or somehow wait for the element to be added to the dom before you can access it.

Comment: I was also expecting to reference the panel right after responding to the (opened) event. Instead of relying on a timer, I used ngDoCheck to check for the reference.

Comment: Ok, just in case it helps someone else, in order to access the "async" result list using `ViewChild` along with the autocomplete reference does the job; for example at the `blur` event I am to do something like `this.autocomplete.options.find(element => element.value === eventValue);` and here it goes the api for it : https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api